# Which phones support which J2ME (Java Micro Edition) spec?

Tags: java, java-me, nokia, smartphone

I just can't find an up-to-date chart about which mobile devices support which Java
Micro Edition version.

I'm especially interested in **Nokia smartphones** and their support for the new **JME 3.0**.

*(I wonder that Sun doesn't seems to provide such information.)*

Please, provide me some links, if you know any!

**EDIT:** I'm probably mixing things up:
**MIDP** seems to be the **mobile Java platform**, while 
**J2ME 3.0** is a **SDK** for it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nokia device specs, including supported JSRs: http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/

Comment: For a Nokia overall JSR x OS Version matrix go to http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_API_support_on_Nokia_devices

Answer (score 4):

You can also have a look at benchmark results as they sometime give a good indication of what is supported on a given phone:

[www.jbenchmark.com](http://www.jbenchmark.com/)

One fairly large curent issue is whether the phones you want to target support MIDP 2.1 (easy to test with a 2.1 helloworld application), like the recent Sony-Ericsson and Nokia handsets.

That version is associated with Mobile Service Architecture (JSR-248), an improvement over Java Technology for the Wireless Industry (JSR-185) which specifies APIs that a handset should support.

Comment: @michael aubert. Please, do you think you could help me with this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121003/j2me-how-to-create-a-master-details-ui/24165313?noredirect=1#comment37322057_24165313

Answer (score 3):

[WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) contains information on which phones have J2ME support, although currently in only covers MIDP 1.0 and 2.0. There's a very handy WURFL query interface at http://wurflpro.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another good resource is the FPC Bench result database: http://www.dpsoftware.org/filter.php.

The site provides a JavaME benchmark application which checks various features and APIs (JSR). The result database contains the results of these benchmarks for free for a wide range of devices. If your device is missing, you can downlaod the the benchmark application, run it on your phone and upload the results.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no Nokia devices available or announced that have support for MIDP 3.0. It seems that the specification hasn't even received the final approval:

http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=271

For information about Nokia devices, I second the link provided by laalto. It also has a search, to filter devices based on a certain feature, such as supported Java APIs.

About the question about classification you added: Java ME is the umbrella covering many different mobile Java technologies. The Java ME specifications most relevant to mobile phones are the CLDC and MIDP. MIDP is the one that contains most of the APIs visible to the developer, so that's often referred to as the platform like you suggested.

However, the "Java ME SDK 3.0" you referred to is a specific product from Sun, containing tools for developing for MIDP and also some other Java ME platforms. Despite the version number of the SDK, the MIDP tools contained do NOT support MIDP 3.0. I don't know if there are any tools available for developing for MIDP 3.0 yet, perhaps someone else has more information about that?

Answer (score 0):

I think almost all phones come with at-least MIDP 2.0 nowadays, at-least in US. I am pretty sure thats the case with a lot of phones. However, one of the ways to find out for sure is to got to the wireless carrier's website, get the list of phones and verify the MIDP info from the manufacturer's website. Thats what I would do.

Comment: For small values of "almost all"... iphone and blackberry don't do MIDP

Answer (score 0):

Another good devices database is [deviceatlas.com](http://deviceatlas.com)