# Resources for determining how widely JSRs are implemented for J2ME

Tags: java-me

Does anyone know of any resources that can give me an idea of how widely various JSRs are implemented?

**Links**

- [Which phones support which spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228515/which-phones-support-which-j2me-java-micro-edition-spec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options none of them are complete :(

1. [J2mePolish's db](http://devices.j2mepolish.org)
2. [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com)
3. [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)
4. Nokia, Sony-Ericsson,* providers websites.

This information isn't aggregated any where really but for JRS information I would say j2mepolish has the greatest source of this information with +- 1000 devices. Although Wurfl and DA have more devices they are mostly targeted and WAP+Mobile Web developers

Comment: That resource although pretty good at phone screen and performance bench marking. doesn't give access to the JSR information.

Answer (score 1):

JBenchmark is quite a substantial database of API compatibilities.

- [www.jbenchmark.com](http://www.jbenchmark.com)